# Nullable type and .HasValue still throws a Null Exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class describing the various Phones stored. Sometimes the `Importance` property can be null. Here is the class

```
public class PhoneTypeListInfo
{
    public string AccountNum { get; set; }
    public int PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }

    public int Importance { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a function that will return a `PhoneTypeListInfo` if the Phone number and account number match a given set of values.

```
    protected PhoneTypeListInfo RetrievePhoneType(string info, string acctNumber)
    {
        PhoneTypeListInfo type = xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info && p.AccountNum == acctNumber).FirstOrDefault();

        return type;
    }
```

This all works great. The problem I'm having is with the linq query below.

```
List<AlertBasedPhones> xAccountPhones = new List<AlertBasedPhones>();
xAccountPhones = (from x in xAccountStuff
                  where x.Media == "Phone"
                  let p = RetrievePhoneType(x.Info, acct.AccountNumber)
                  let xyz = x.Importance = (p.Importance as int?).HasValue ? p.Importance : 0
                  orderby p.Importance descending
                  select x).ToList();
```

What I am doing above is attempting to use a different class that has a different composition, except for obtaining the 'Importance' property from the PhoneTypeListInfo.

My question ultimately is, What do I need to do to allow `p.Importance` to be null, and set it to 0 if it is null, making `x.Importance` 0 as well.

Comment: I don't think it is `p.Importannce` that is null, but `p` itself.

Comment: I think Scott is right, you would need an extra check for p itself since `RetrievePhoneType` can return  `null`

Comment: the null progagating operator ?. might be useful here.

Comment: since importance is not a nullable int this expression: `(p.Importance as int?).HasValue` is always true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not that `p.Importannce` that is null, but `p` itself. That is the thing you need to check for null first. If you are using C# 6 you can use the `?.` operator. You can also smiplifiy the logic of `(p.Importance as int?).HasValue ? p.Importance : 0` to `p.Importance ?? 0`. Combining both you get

```
List<AlertBasedPhones> xAccountPhones = new List<AlertBasedPhones>();
xAccountPhones = (from x in xAccountStuff
                         where x.Media == "Phone"
                         let p = RetrievePhoneType(x.Info, acct.AccountNumber)
                         let xyz = x.Importance = p?.Importance ?? 0
                         orderby p?.Importance descending
                         select x).ToList();
```

Comment: p is not null. I will test Roberts answer, but it looks like I should have used a ternary instead.

Comment: @ChrisClark If 0 rows match `xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info && p.AccountNum == acctNumber)` then `p` will be null. Robert's answer is doing the same null check with `(null==p)`, I am just using the more convient `?.` operator introduced with C# 6.

Comment: @ChrisClark if you are confident that you will never have a situation where  `xPhoneTypeList.Where(p => p.PhoneNum == info && p.AccountNum == acctNumber)` returns 0 rows then change `.FirstOrDefault()` to `.First()`, that way a exception will be thrown if there was 0 rows (but if there is never 0 rows it won't be a problem)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I used ternary instead, because this is not c# 6.0

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, as I am sure this would have worked if I had c# 6.0. I changed `orderby p?.Importance descending` to `x.Importance descending`. and using `x.Importance = (p == null) ? 0 : p.Importance` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator. Replace `p.Importance` with `(null==p) ? 0 : p.Importance`